# Наследование от классов стандартной библиотеки

Tags: c++

Как любитель интересных решений, подумал для реализации своего класса более эффективным способом, написать smartest_iterator, но чтобы облегчить свою задачу, решил воспользоваться наследованием:

```
template < class T >
class smartest_iterator : public std::ostream_iterator<T> {
    smartest_iterator(ostream_type& os, char* delim) 
        :ostream_iterator<T>(os, delim) {}
    //... ну и дальше, думаю, не имеет отношения к вопросу 
};
```

В программировании я лишь любитель - новычок, но у меня есть знакомый программист, который мне сказал, что не рекомендуется так делать, т. е. наследовать от библиотечных классов. Мой вопрос: если он прав, то почему?.. И прав ли он?

Comment: Гм... Откровенно говоря, "Не вижу препятствий!" (с)

Comment: @Harry, обычно к недостаткам относят отсутствие виртуального деструктора... но мы же не собираемся использовать полиморфизм. )

Comment: Вот как раз *"ну и дальше, думаю, не имеет отношения к вопросу"* следовало бы привести. Использование наследования там, где можно обойтись написанием отдельной функции или агрегацией является весьма распространённой ошибкой.

Comment: @Croessmah, так и есть - полиморфизму тут нет место

Comment: @Harry, спасибо,  меня радует положительный ответ, потому что я  нигде не читал обратное, ну и по логике вроде бы не должно быть  никакого побочного эффекта.

Comment: @VTT,  над агрегацией подумаю, но отдельная функция в данном вопросе не получится, а не привел, потому что немного сложно написал, и мне еще предстоит оптимизировать

Comment: Наследоваться от стандартных классов, в общем случае, плохая затея. Они для этого не предназначены. Была у меня история, деталей которой я точно не помню, но суть была в том, что MSVS 2010 не могла собрать Qt 4.8(?) и 5.x, потому что в WebKit (который входил в Qt) было наследование от стандартного класса, который, в свою очередь, наследовался от какой-то внутренней реализации. И вот вся эта мешанина ломала компиляцию из-за подобного наследования.

Comment: @ ixSci, ясно,  полезная инфа

Answer (score 0):

Книга "С++ Стандартная библиотека" Николай Джосъютис, стр. 292, на которой автор пишет свой класс итератора с наследованием от библиотечного std::iterator.
Не слушайте знакомых, читайте книги.

Comment: вот я и вас послушал, но это же мне не повредило...

Comment: `std::iterator`, однако, является deprecated начиная с С++17. За актуальностью книг тоже нужно следить.

Comment: @AnT стандарты приходят и уходят, а поддержка приложений остается. Где гарантия, что завтра то, что использовали сегодня, не станет deprecated? :)